# Is there something wrong with my for loop/if statement?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a for loop within a for loop and right before I enter an if statement, two values echo out and are equal.  When I evaluate (with the if statement) whether or no they are equal, the values do not evaluate to even.  Could there be something that I am not seeing that is wrong with this statement?

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($movies_total);$x++){

                for($j = 0; $j < count($ask_array);$j++){
                    echo $movies_total[$x]->question_id.' '.$ask_array[$j].'<br>';
                    if($movies_total[$x]->question_id == $ask_array[$j]){
                        echo 'no';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is there any whitespace at the start or end of the values you are comparing?  Try outputting quotes in your `echo` statement around the values, like `echo '"' . $movies_total[$x]->question_id . '" "' . $ask_array[$j] . '"<br/>';`

Comment: Can you show us the output of the program? This might help us solve the issue.

Comment: Dump both values into a file and expect that with a hex editor. Most likely some whitespace which you won't see in a browser output or some other exotic character which looks the same but actually differs.

Answer (score 0):

You should dump both your variables ( $movies_total[$x] , $ask_array ) for us to know the problem but my guess would be you have white spaces. You can compare variables after trim:

```
if( trim($movies_total[$x]->question_id) == trim($ask_array[$j]) )
```